# how to remove line break '%0D' from file name in csh

Tags: sed, typing-break

I want to download some data using wget command from list of files, I used foll. code:

```
    foreach file(`cat Model_list1.txt`)

     echo $file
     wget https://jeodpp.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/LISCOAST/10011/LATEST/EURO-CORDEX/EUR-11/SMHI-RCA4/"$file"/BC/historical/prAdjust_EUR-11_"$file"_historical_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1-JRC-SBC-EOBS10-1981-2010_day_19810101-20101231.nc.gz
end
```

However, for every file name I am getting %0D at the end of the file name. I tried sed as follow to change the name of the file located in the file Model_list but still I am getting the same error. Kindly help me out. Thanks

```
sed 's/%0D//g' Model_list.txt > Model_list1.txt
```

where my Model_list.txt is

```
CNRM-CERFACS-CNRM-CM5
ICHEC-EC-EARTH
IPSL-IPSL-CM5A-MR
MOHC-HadGEM2-ES
MPI-M-MPI-ESM-LR
```

Comment: there is a rename and a rename.ul command in linux. you can just do rename "%0D" "" filename.

Comment: `%0D` is carriage return (I think windows). So your source file has this at the end of every line.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185095/remove-0d-from-variable-in-bash)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a few lines from your `Model_list1.txt`. Copy the lines and paste them directly into your question, then use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format them as code. That way, we can have an exact example of your input to understand what's going on. The `%0D` won't be part of your file, that's from wget trying to encode a URL and failing. But we need to see the file to understand. Also, what language are you writing in? That isn't a valid shell command. Is that PHP? Something else?

Comment: @terdon it's valid `csh` syntax I think (although has the same word-splitting issues as a bash for / cat loop)

Comment: @steeldriver ah, `csh`. [I try to forget that people use that for scripting](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) ;). user962808, since Ubuntu defaults to bash and/or dash, if this is indeed csh, please mention that in your question.

Comment: OK. I solved it using sed: sed 's/\r//g' Model_list.txt > Model_list1.txt